# what does Hadley mean by dbplyr being meant for smaller datasets?

Tags: r, dplyr, dbi, dbplyr

I was searching for ways to try and measure peak RAM usage with `dbplyr` when I found [this github issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/96). The poster asked about using `copy_to()` to copy from one database to another without bringing the tbl into RAM, and Hadley replies:

> I think this is out of scope for dbplyr; the idea of these tools is to make it possible to work with smaller datasets. For anything large, you really need to deal with it in your own data pipeline.

I've been using `dbplyr` with `MonetDBLite` lately to work with some data sets that are too large for memory, sometimes using `copy_to()` to write intermediary data along the way, with mostly good results, so I'm confused as to what he means by this and if I am missing something important.

#### Working example

Just to work through a (toy) example, let's say I have the following .csv file:

```
# produces ~700Mb file, in ~25 seconds (on my machine)
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  mutate(replicate = list(1:500000)) %>%
  unnest(replicate) %>%
  arrange(replicate) %>%
  write_csv("big.csv")
```

I want to add 1 to all of the values using the dplyr front end and save the result for later processing.

With tibbles, the following seems to peak at about 4.3GB RAM usage:

```
big.modified <- read_csv("big.csv") %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ .x + 1))
```

With `MonetDBLite` + `dbplyr`, the following seems to run fine and uses a negligible amount of RAM:

```
library(DBI)
library(MonetDBLite)
con <- dbConnect(MonetDBLite::MonetDBLite(), "example.db")
# read, streaming
monetdb.read.csv(con, "big.csv", "big")

tbl(con, "big") %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ .x + 1)) %>%
  copy_to(con, ., "big_modified", temporary = FALSE)
```

Same results:

```
all.equal(as.data.frame(big.modified),
          as.data.frame(tbl(con, "big_modified") %>% collect()))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Unlike `DBI::dbWriteTable()`, which if used above seems to cost about 1.5GB peak RAM, `copy_to()` doesn't seem to be using hardly any memory.

#### Question

I've started using pipes similar in form to the example above in what I'd intend to eventually be production code, and `copy_to()` seems so far to successfully avoid copying via RAM. Unless I'm missing something, `dbplyr` would seem to deliver (partially) on the [oft-requested ability to work in R with out-of-memory data as does SAS](https://community.rstudio.com/t/best-practice-to-handle-out-of-memory-data/734) -- at least until you run into something `dbplyr` can't translate to SQL or which is unable to accept a `tbl` natively (e.g., many kinds of modeling functions, I would assume?).

Maybe the difference between my case and that of the github poster's is that I'm working with just one database, while they were trying to transfer between two, but I'm still confused as to Hadley's response. The `dbplyr` [introduction](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/dbplyr.html) explicitly states that one of the main purposes of the package is to make it easier to work with data that don't fit into RAM, so I'm confused as to what he means by it being intended for "smaller datasets." And does "deal with it in your own data pipeline" mean to write your own SQL? I'm trying to understand what limitation(s) he is talking about, as I've been (tentatively) adopting `dbplyr` in more of my code.

Comment: My interepreation of Hadley's comments is: if you ever have to bring the database to local RAM storage, to then upload to another database, you will quickly run out of memory. Therfore, dbplyr is meant for 'smaller' (i.e. < RAM sized) datasets. If you need more, then you will have to implement your own streaming/chunking/data handling process.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks. But the `dbplyr` documentation says that it is meant for > RAM sized datasets (see link in last paragraph). It says that if your data fit in RAM, there's no point in putting it in a database.

Comment: Yes, but not for copying databases back to local storage to then copy to another remote database. dbplyr and any other database package allows you to work with data stored elsewhere that is bigger than RAM, but not to ever represent the whole db locally.

Comment: But that's probably not a super common use case, right? It still seems strange to me to say that the point of dbplyr is to make it possible to work with smaller datasets, when everything else seems to say the opposite. And much of the design seems to be around avoiding bringing things into RAM, as you'd expect for something intended for larger-than-memory data. Am I wrong in perceiving a contradiction here?

Comment: I think you're conflating what dbplyr is for generally, versus what dbplyr specifically is not setup to do in this particular github issue. There's no contradiction to say the package is for out-of-memory analysis, but not for copying from database to database.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe it comes from a misreading of "these tools." I've been interpreting that mean `dbplyr` as a whole, whereas he perhaps intended it to just mean some particular aspect(s) of the functionality of `copy_to()`, which are not relevant to my usage.